# Output in multi threading program

Tags: c, pthreads

Writing my basic programs on multi threading and I m coming across several difficulties.

In the program below if I give sleep at position 1 then value of shared data being printed is always 10 while keeping sleep at position 2 the value of shared data is always 0.

Why this kind of output is coming ?
How to decide at which place we should give sleep.
Does this mean that if we are placing a sleep inside the mutex then the other thread is not being executed at all thus the shared data being 0.

```
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include<unistd.h>

    pthread_mutex_t lock;

    int shared_data = 0;

    void * function(void *arg)
    {
        int i ;
        for(i =0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            shared_data++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        }

        pthread_exit(NULL); 
    }


    int main()
    {
        pthread_t thread;
        void * exit_status;
        int i;

        pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);

        i = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, function, NULL);

        for(i =0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            sleep(1);      //POSITION 1
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            //sleep(1);    //POSITION 2
            printf("Shared data value is %d\n", shared_data);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        }

        pthread_join(thread, &exit_status);

        pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you sleep before you lock the mutex, then you're giving the other thread plenty of time to change the value of the shared variable.  That's why you're seeing a value of "10" with the 'sleep' in position #1.

When you grab the mutex first, you're able to lock it fast enough that you can print out the value before the other thread has a chance to modify it.  The other thread sits and blocks on the `pthread_mutex_lock()` call until your main thread has finished sleeping and unlocked it.  At that point, the second thread finally gets to run and alter the value.  That's why you're seeing a value of "0" with the 'sleep' at position #2.

This is a classic case of a race condition.  On a different machine, the same code might not display "0" with the `sleep` call at position #2.  It's entirely possible that the second thread has the opportunity to alter the value of the variable once or twice before your main thread locks the mutex.  A mutex can ensure that two threads don't access the same variable at the same time, but it doesn't have any control over the order in which the two threads access it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a full explanation here but ended up deleting it. This is a basic synchronization problem and you should be able to trace and identify it before tackling anything more complicated.

But I'll give you a hint: It's only the `sleep()` in position 1 that matters; the other one inside the lock is irrelevant as long as it doesn't change the code outside the lock.